# Getting success call with array length 0, when service is unavailable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two method for my query-
query: {method: 'GET' isArray: true}
save:{method: 'POST'}

When service is down surely I should get an HTTP error like 400 or 404.
But here am getting error callback for my save.

For query, am getting an array length of 0 with success. That is not correct in any sense.

```
Api.Loc.query(function(res) {
var resArray = res;
if(resArray && resArray.length == 0){ 
    $scope.addErrorAlert("Services are currently not responding.Please try again later.",true);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, if there is an error then it will return the exception and status.

```js
var  endPoint  = 'https://google.com';

 $http.get(endPoint,{ cache: false })
      .success(deferred.resolve)
      .error(function(data,status){
       deferred.reject();
});
```